# Rewrite non-existing folder to be query without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a way of getting `example.com/159985870458322944/`, or any other random 18-digit string, to be rewritten to `example.com/?159985870458322944`, where that string is a query key. It also needs to not change URL, so that the URL stays `example.com/159985870458322944`, but shows content that the index.php in the main directory (`example.com/`) gets thru the query.

---

I currently have this (not working)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /?$1 [NC,P]
</IfModule>
```

Which does not work, as expected. I tried a lot of things I found, but didnt get any of the solutions working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `P` or proxy for this, just rewrite internally like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d{18})/?$ /?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh well; thank you! Seems to work pretty well. Now I just need to fix my PHP for it cause it cannot get the query it previously had, but that shouldn't be a hard job. Thanks a lot!